# Rails query: Attempting to find errors in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, `CheckIn`, that belongs to both `Client` and `Program` in such a way that both `client_id` and `program_id` are fields.  `Program` also belongs to `Client`.  I'm attempting to locate all `check_ins` where the `Program` that they belong to, belongs to **a different** client.

I've noticed this mismatch on a few records and I'm trying to determine how frequently this occurred.

```
class CheckIn < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :program
    belongs_to :client
end

class Program < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :check_ins
    has_many :programs
end
```

An example of a record with a mismatch that I would like to query for would be something like this because the program it belongs to **does not** belong to the same client:

```
#<CheckIn:0x00000001149ef9e8> {
  :id => 336964,
  :created_at => Wed, 29 Jun 2022 17:06:19.567000000 EDT -04:00,
  :updated_at => Wed, 29 Jun 2022 17:06:30.280633000 EDT -04:00,
  :client_id => 45290,
  :program_id => 26266,
}

#<Program:0x00000001141e4d70
  id: 26266,
  client_id: 46220, # should match CheckIn (45290)
  created_at: Tue, 18 Oct 2022 07:19:13.735740000 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 18 Oct 2022 07:19:13.735740000 EDT -04:00
>
```

How might I write that query?  I tried the following but don't know how to access the `CheckIn`'s `client_id`:

```
CheckIn.joins(:program).where.not(programs: {client_id: CLIENT_ID_HERE})
```

Comment: I am not sure I even understand this schema. If a `Program` belongs to a `Client` explicitly then what is the need for `CheckIn` to reference the `Client`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
CheckIn.joins(:program).where('programs.client_id <> check_ins.client_id')
```

Comment: That's awesome!  I didn't realize you could access `check_ins` like that!